# How do you perform a recursive operation in MIPS Assembly?

Tags: assembly, recursion, mips

I've been tasked with writing a recursive MIPS assembly program that executes the following mathematical operation within function1:

```
(-3)*function1(n-2) + 7*function1(n-3) + 15
```

The program is modeled in c:

```
 // The function1 is a recursive procedure defined by:
// function1(n) = 1 if n <= 2
// = (-3)*function1(n-2) + 7*function1(n-3) + 15 otherwise.
int function1(int n)
{
 if (n <= 2)
 {
 return 1;
 }
 else
 {
 int comp = (-3)*function1(n-2) + 7*function1(n-3) + 15;
 return comp;
 }
}
// The main calls function1 by entering an integer given by a user.
void main()
1 of 2{
 int ans, n;
 printf("Enter an integer:\n");
 // read an integer from user and store it in "n"
 scanf("%d", &n);
 ans = function1(n);
 // print out the solution computed by function 1
 printf("The solution is: %d\n", ans);
 return;
}
```

I've written the code, which compiles and executes fine, but gives me incorrect values:

```
 .data
mes1:   .asciiz "\nEnter an integer: "
mes2:   .asciiz "The solutinon is: "

.text
    .globl main

main:
    #Display message
    la $a0, mes1
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    #Retrieve Value
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    #Store value into $a0 and jump to function1
    move $a0, $v0
    jal function1

    #Store return value to $t0
    move $t0, $v0

    #Display solution
    la $a0, mes2
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    move $a0, $t0
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    #End
    li $v0, 10
    syscall



function1:
    #Store return address
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $ra, 0($sp)

    #Store $a0 to stack
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $a0, 0($sp)

    #If($a0<3):$t0=1:$t0=0
    slti $t0, $a0, 3

    #if($t0=0):math
    beq $t0, $zero, math
    addi $v0, $zero, 1

    #Retrieve from stack
    lw  $a0, 0($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 4
    lw  $ra, 0($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 4

    jr $ra

math:
    addi $a0, $a0, -2
    jal function1
    mul $s0 $v0, -3
    addi $a0, $a0, -3
    jal function1
    mul $s1, $v0, 7
    add $s1, $s0, $s1
    addi $v0, $s1, 15

    #Retrieve from stack
    lw  $a0, 0($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 4
    lw  $ra, 0($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 4

    jr $ra
```

When I enter 6, it's supposed to output 91. Currently, it's outputting 44. Perhaps more disconcerting, whenever I enter any value, the output number is always divisible by 4. For the life of me, I can't figure out what is wrong. Can anyone advise?

-Edit-

I took into account @Tomás Badan comment regarding protecting $a0. I tried:

```
math:
    #Store $a0 to stack
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $a0, 0($sp)

    addi $a0, $a0, -2
    jal function1
    mul $s0, $v0, -3

    #Retrieve from stack
    lw  $a0, 0($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 4

    addi $a0, $a0, -3
    jal function1
    mul $s1, $v0, 7
    add $s1, $s0, $s1
    addi $v0, $s1, 15

    #Retrieve from stack
    lw  $a0, 0($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 4
    lw  $ra, 0($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 4

    jr $ra
```

But it's still returning incorrect values, although closer to the correct number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'll appoint some errors, this is not a complete debug session:

```
function1:
...
#If($a0<3):$t0=1:$t0=0
slti $t0, $a0, 3

#if($t0=0):sub1
beq $t0, $zero, math

#Load 4 to $v0
addi $v0, $zero, 4 // I thought you should return 1
...

math:
addi $a0, $a0, -2  // you are changing $a0 here
jal function1
lw $t2, constn3
mult $v0, $t2
mflo $t0           // you use $t0 to keep temporary values, but you function change $t0 too (look above, at instruction slti). You need to protect its contents
addi $a0, $a0, -3  // but you need your original value here
jal function1
lw $t2, const7
mult $v0, $t2
```

**EDITED**

As I said in comments, you need to keep all register that need to keep state between procedure calls.

If you follow the MIPS conventions calls, it says that you must save any register from s* series that you use inside of your functions. You use two of them s0 and s1, so, you must save them at the entry point. Hmmm, that is another question, you must have only one entry point and only one exit point.

```
function1:
#Store return address
addi $sp, $sp, -12
sw $ra, 0($sp)
sw $s0, 4($sp)
sw $s1, 8($sp)

#If($a0<3):$t0=1:$t0=0
slti $t0, $a0, 3

#if($t0=0):math
beq $t0, $zero, math
addi $v0, $zero, 1
j exit

math:
addi $sp, $sp, -4
sw $a0, 0($sp)
addi $a0, $a0, -2
jal function1
lw  $a0, 0($sp)
addi    $sp, $sp, 4

addi $t6, $zero, -3
mul $s0 $v0, $t6

addi $sp, $sp, -4
sw $a0, 0($sp)
addi $a0, $a0, -3
jal function1
lw  $a0, 0($sp)
addi    $sp, $sp, 4

addi $t6, $zero, 7
mul $s1, $v0, $t6
add $s1, $s0, $s1
addi $v0, $s1, 15

#Retrieve from stack
exit:
lw $ra, 0($sp)
lw $s0, 4($sp)
lw $s1, 8($sp)
addi    $sp, $sp, 12

jr $ra
```

Comment: I've updated my code. On the addi $v0, $zero, 4 line should have been 1 not 4. In regards to your second comment, I believe I am supposed to decrement $a0 by 2 until function1 returns 1. In regards to your 3rd comment, I've done away with mflo and just used mul. I've also used different registers so that I don't overwrite them. In regards to comment 4, once again, I thought this was handled by the stack and necessary similar to comment 2?

Comment: Entering 6 now results in -35

Comment: As a example, if n=5, you must call your function as: `(-3)*function1(3) + 7*function1(2) + 15`. In your code, you call the first function1 with $a0 = 3, but in the second call, your $a0 = 3 - 3, that is 0

Comment: That makes sense... I guess the stack doesn't return the original value? How do you recommend handling this?

Comment: Protect the values before calling the function, pushing on the stack and pop them after calling the function

Comment: If you have the time, would you mind showing my how you would do this? Everything I can think of overwrites or is overwritten by something else.

Comment: For the record, 2 returns 1 and -1 returns 1, both of which are correct.

Comment: Without going in too much detail, you need to note that you are calling a recursive function. So, any value, or state, that you need to keep before and after you call you function, you need to protect it onto stack. For example, you need to keep $s0 valid after your function calls. but inside your function, you are altering $s0, so, in order to work, you need to save it onto stack before you call your function and pop it back after you had called it